# Check if a variable have only one letter or a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I have my variable `$_GET['artist']` and I'd like to check :

1. if that variable have got only `one` letter, and this letter is from `a` to `z` (case sensitive, so `A` is not valid);
2. or if that variable is `all` or `other`

How can I check it with `regex` and `preg_match()` on PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^([a-z]|all|other)$/', $_GET['artist']) === 1) {
    // True
}
```

Assuming `all` and `other` should also be case sensitive.

Comment: Uhm...that's the problem! If I wrote "othe" it works too...I don't want this :) The same if I wrote for example "hh"... I need specific values... P.S. I tried without ===1

Comment: Yes, the one I see right now... but without ===1, just evalutate the "true" with (preg_match('/^([a-z]|all|other)$/', $_GET['artist']))

Comment: It's always good to see an answer that doesn't replicate functionality that PHP already has but rather uses it.

Comment: @kwichz Sorry I don't understand. `var_dump` of `preg_match('/^([a-z]|all|other)$/', 'other')` show it returns `1`, doing the same for `othe` returns `0`.

Comment: @Ben - Speak about "clueless".

Comment: `\pL` is only half as long as `[a-z]`, and almost always works better, too.

Comment: @kwichz What does `var_dump(preg_match('/^([a-z]|all|other)$/', 'othe'));` output for you?